# Rails 4.2: "Assets should not be requested directly without their digests"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

On Rails 4.2.0.beta1 I get an error:

> Assets should not be requested directly without their digests: Use the helpers in ActionView::Helpers to request fonts/source-sans-pro.woff

The stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Source Sans Pro'), local('SourceSansPro-Regular'), url(/assets/source-sans-pro.woff) format('woff');
}
```

The configuration is:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.precompile += %w(.svg .eot .woff .ttf)
```

Sure I can disable digests and it works again, but I'm interested in using them. Therefore, how do I make use of digests when I need to request `source-sans-pro.woff`?

Please note that I place the fonts in `assets/fonts` directory, not the `public/` directory. I don't see a difference between images and fonts, so I want to keep them under the same directory - `app/assets`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [font_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-font_path) helper. You have to be sure the stylesheet has the `filename.css.scss` format for this to work.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Source Sans Pro'), local('SourceSansPro-Regular'), url(font_path('source-sans-pro.woff')) format('woff');
}
```

Comment: See also `asset-url` for related finding.